# hover effect on the TR 's TD

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have defined the following inside my css:-

```
 .mainTr {
       background-color:#78a22f;
       color:white;
   }
   .mainTr :hover{
       background-color: #C1D72E;
       color:#78a22f;
   }
```

and i have the following TR:-

```
 <tr class="mainTr">
                        <td><b>SPECIFICATIONS</b></td>
                        <td><b>FEATURES</b></td>
                    </tr>
```

but currently when i hover over a TR only on TD will got the new hover effect and for its text color while the background color will not be #C1D72E, also the other TD will keep rendering the defualt behavioure ..

[image]

Comment: For what I see about your code I can do two guess: you have an invalid html markup or your .mainTr:hover rule is being overwritten by some css that is coming after the section you posted. Have you tried to check what CSS is involved while hovering? What firebug or developer's tool report to be applied?

Answer (score 0):

I think u did not use table tag when u using tr and td tag example below:

## html:

```
<table> 
<tr class="mainTr">
      <td><b>SPECIFICATIONS</b></td>
      <td><b>FEATURES</b></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

## CSS:

```
.mainTr{
       background:#78a22f;
       color:white;
       padding:10px;
}
 .mainTr:hover{
       background-color:#C1D72E;
       color:#78a22f;
 }
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Grald/qd6c2zww/